# flatten and uneven array into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, lodash

I have this Array and Object representing the same data:

```
arrayExample = [
  {name: "max", age: 21},
  {name: "max.David", age: 27},
  {name: "max.Sylvia"},
  {name: "max.David.Jeff"},
  {name: "max.Sylvia.Anna", age: 20},
  {name: "max.David.Buffy"},
  {name: "max.Sylvia.Craig"},
  {name: "max.Sylvia.Robin"}
];
ObjectExample = {
  name: "max",
  age: 21,
  children: [
    {
      name: "Sylvia",
      children: [
        {name: "Craig"},
        {name: "Robin"},
        {name: "Anna", age: 20}
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "David",
      age: 27,
      children: [
        {name: "Jeff"},
        {name: "Buffy"}
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

my objective is to extend the Array class to have 2 functions flatten which transform the objectExample into the arrayExample and uneven which do the opposite, I'm thinking maybe lodash would help here but I still didn't find the correct way to do this here's where I'm now:
to flatten from objectExample to arrayExample first the objectExample structure must be specific meaning the parents must share a property with all their children sure the parents and children could have other property that should be ported to the proper item in the new arrayExample, also for the uneven function it should create an object that all the parents share the same property with their children and other property should be copied respectively.
To give my use case for this I'm trying to make a [d3js tree layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout) of [angular ui router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router) in my application that will be generated from the routes JSON file since I make the routes in a JSON file.

## update:

my specific problem is that I need to create a d3js tree layout for angular-ui-router configurations states object which I can extract into a json file as I said before, the structure for the ui-router is like the arrayExample, and the required structure for the d3js tree layout is like the objectExample, one way to go about this is to manually rewrite it and it wont take too much time but that solution is not what I want I need to make a build task for this for generic routes that will always have the name attribute in their config object that could be used to find children of each route or state, for more information check [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) for routes config object and this d3 videos for d3 tre layout:

- [part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8dwXoWODZ4).
- [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZ6MSHA4FMU).

**correction**: extending the Object class with a flatten function to flatten an object into an array and the Array class with unEven function to unEven an array into an object not like I wrote before:

> my objective is to extend the Array class to have 2 functions.

## update 2:

To make this more clear, both flatten and unEven are like the map function except flatten is for an object not an array and it return an array, and the unEven function is for an array but return an object.

Comment: What specific problem are you running into?

Comment: Does the output of flattening have to be in the exact order in `arrayExample`?  I ask because that is not the natural order from a recursive algorithm so it would be more work to get that specific order.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @jfriend00  the order is not importent.

Comment: @Sukima check Update and if steal XY problem please clarify more, thanks.

Comment: @jfriend00 if you have read the question you would find that I stated that the solution should copy any additional property if present.

Comment: And the fact that two people wrote answers that don't do what you want apparently shows how clear the question is.  If you include sample input and output you should put everything in it you want.  Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that will produce the flattened output:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/w134L7c6/

```
var ObjectExample = {
  name: "max",
  age: 35,
  status: "single",
  hometown: "Scottsdale",
  children: [
    {
      name: "Sylvia",
      children: [
          {name: "Craig", age: 16},
        {name: "Robin"},
        {name: "Anna"}
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "David",
      age: 54,
      children: [
        {name: "Jeff"},
        {name: "Buffy"}
      ]
    }
  ]
};

// call this on an object with a name property
// and an optional children property (which would be an array of objects)
function flatten(obj, key, outputArray, rootName) {
    var name, item;
    outputArray = outputArray || [];
    rootName = rootName || "";
    if (rootName) {
        rootName += ".";
    }
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        name = rootName + obj[key];
        item = {};
        item[key] = name;
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop !== "children") {
                item[prop] = obj[prop];
            }
        }
        outputArray.push(item)
        if (obj.children) {
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
                flatten(obj.children[i], key, outputArray, name);
            }
        }
    }
    return outputArray;
}

var result = flatten(ObjectExample, "name");
```

Produces this output:

```
[{"name":"max","age":35,"status":"single","hometown":"Scottsdale"},
{"name":"max.Sylvia"},
{"name":"max.Sylvia.Craig","age":16},
{"name":"max.Sylvia.Robin"},
{"name":"max.Sylvia.Anna"},
{"name":"max.David","age":54},
{"name":"max.David.Jeff"},
{"name":"max.David.Buffy"}]
```

You could adapt this function to be a method on the Array prototype if you really want to (not something I would recommend, particularly since the input isn't even an array).

I do not know what you mean when you say "the rootName could have more then one".  `ObjectExample` is an object and thus cannot have more than one name at the top level.  If you started with an array of `ObjectExample` like structures, then you could just loop over the array calling `flatten()` on each object in the top level array and it would accumulate the results.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't do it, check my question I want that the if parent or children have more properties those properties will be copied too, also it should not be restricted to name property, that should be supplied as argument and the rootName we could have more then one.

Comment: @YahyaKACEM - I modified my answer to copy the additional properties over and pass in the key property string for name accumulation.  I don't know what your comment about rootName means.

Comment: Thanks, for this response it's as close as possible to what I want, also thanks for correcting my question you and [@Sukima](http://stackoverflow.com/users/227176/sukima) were correct I'll reformat my question one last time after I use this answer and get it to work as I wanted and failed to explain it correctly.

Comment: Hi, please  check updated question if you have more comments please share them so I can fix what may still be incorrect, thanks.

Comment: @yahyakacem - you've completely changed your question.  That is not how stack overflow works.  If you want to ask a 2nd question, then start a new question and put this question back the way it was.